# How to resolve this node affinity with Envoy

Tags: load-balancing, grpc, envoyproxy

I provide a gRPC service that unfortunately has to have node affinity between `BeginTransaction` and `Commit` API Calls.

The Consumer API calls sequence is typically:

1. `BeginTransaction()` returns `txnID`
2. `DoStuff(txnID, moreParams...)`
3. `DoStuff(txnID, moreParams...)`
4. `...`
5. `Commit(txnID)`

Consumers can be multithreaded processes that make simultaneous calls to my API, so they might be using hundreds of Transactions at any point in time.

If I use Envoy proxy as my Service entry point, `BeginTransaction` should be routed to any healthy node in the cluster, but it must ensure that subsequent calls that use the returned `txnID` are routed to the same node.

Passing any context info in http headers, or in whatsoever part of the messages, is acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I made some progress using Ring Hash balancer

In the envoy proxy server (look for "hash"):

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: http2
          stat_prefix: ingress_http #just for statistics
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: samplefront_virtualhost
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/mycompany.sample.v1"
                  grpc: {}
                route:
                  cluster: sampleserver
                  hash_policy:
                    header:
                      header_name: "x-session-hash"
              - match:
                  prefix: "/bbva.sample.admin"
                  grpc: {}
                route:
                  cluster: sampleadmin
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: sampleserver
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: ring_hash
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: sampleserver
        port_value: 80 #Connect to the Sidecard Envoy
  - name: sampleadmin
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: sampleadmin
        port_value: 80 #Connect to the Sidecard Envoy
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
```

In my consumers, I create a random hash just before `BeginTransaction()` and I make sure it is sent in the `x-session-hash` header every single time until `Commit(txnId)`

It works but it has some limitations:

When I scale up the service, adding more nodes, some operations fail with error `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers`. Failures are absolutely ok when one node is lost, but they are hardly acceptable when a node is added!!! Good news is that the load gets rebalanced in both cases.

The client must generate the hash before the first call (`BeginTransaction`) is made, so is the client who is inadvertently dictating which node will attend the requests for this transaction.

I will keep investigating.